# Measuring algorithm calculation time (using MPI, parallel computing)

Tags: c, mpi, parallel-processing

http://pastebin.com/Xb6GLv8Y

My code does the following:

It will be executed in parallel, in a cluster. The master rank will generate an descendent-ordered array with lots of elements (maximum 1.6M elements), will divide this array into smaller arrays, will send each of these parts to each of the computers in the cluster. Each computer in the cluster will perform a quicksort algorithm in it's part of the array and will send back this (ascendent-ordered) array to the master rank. The master rank will then use a modified bubble sort algorithm to sort each parts received from the child ranks and build the new ordered array. (The objective is to perform the quicksort algorithm in parallel computing).

Everything is working perfectly fine, the unique problem is that I need to measure the computing time of the algorithm. It is a university work, so the PDF says to "calculate the time ONLY for the ordering algorithm". So I think its not to consider the array transfer between the network and etc.

What I did in the code is to measure the quicksort elapsed time for every child rank. The biggest time will be the computing time. Am I right? But there is a problem. Look the output:

```
Array final, first 1, last 800000
Vetor de 800000 elementos ordenado com quicksort em paralelo (99 threads).
Dentre o tempo de processamento de cada node, o maior foi 140000, 0.14 seconds.

Array final, first 1, last 1600000
Vetor de 1600000 elementos ordenado com quicksort em paralelo (99 threads).
Dentre o tempo de processamento de cada node, o maior foi 560000, 0.56 seconds.
```

It says the maximum time of a child performing quicksort was 0.56 seconds. But I waited like 30 seconds before the last result was printed. Is that absurd difference normal? Am I measuring the time correctly?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You said your code _will_ be run on a cluster; how many processes was this particular test run on?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of  things could be happening.

1. You are not counting time for sort and joinArrays in rank0, after the child processes are done.
2. Each child took 0.56sec, but starting time of each child need not be same. I don't know what kind of communication fabric your cluster has, but given small amount of data you are moving, I doubt that would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the time for the entire sort, then you must measure the time taken until the last processor finishes. You can accomplish this by taking the finishing time after an MPI_Barrier.

A 60x speed difference between nodes means that you have poor load balancing. Some nodes are doing way more work than others, and if you want good performance you'll have to find a way to equalize the loads a bit more.

If you're interested in parallel sorting then I recommend you read up on the [PSort](http://www.allthingshpc.org/Publications/psort.pdf) algorithm and [source code](http://gauss.cs.ucsb.edu/code/psort/psort-1.0.tar.gz). It does a local sort then some minimal communication to figure out which processors should get which part, then a mass transfer of data to their destination processors. It has a minimum amount of communication overhead.